# Problem with formating decimal places in Javascript

Tags: javascript, decimal

I have a problem with decimal places. My code gives me the result 123 123 12, while I need to display the result in the form 12 312 312.

Can anyone help setting this formatting?

Code here:

```
        var fcqInteger = parseInt(fcq.replace(/\s/g, ''));
        valPrice = parseFloat(valPrice.replace(',', '.'));
        var marketCap = (fcqInteger * valPrice)+'';
        // result
        var marketCapParts = marketCap.match(/[\s\S]{1,3}/g) || []; 
        marketCap = marketCapParts.join(' ');
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What contains `fcq` and `valPrice` ?

Comment: A constant value that doesn't change. This is not an important variable. The most important is the variable is marketCap.

Comment: And `valPrice` ?

Comment: This is important to be able to reproduce

Comment: Another variable that gets the value from outside. It is formatted because it must format the result.

Comment: @Cid No. Everything before `// result` is irrelevant. The question is how to format a stringified number in `marketCap`, how `marketCap` gets its value is unimportant (and should not even be in the question, really, as it's a distraction).

Answer (score 4):

You could replace with space by looking to the end of the string for groupd of three.

```js
var data = '12312312'

console.log(data.replace(/.{1,3}(?=(...)+$)/g, '$& '));  // replace
console.log(data.match(/.{1,3}(?=(...)*$)/g).join(' ')); // match/join
```

Comment: It works, buy your code shortens my 8 character number to 5, so from 123 123 12 it gets 12 312. How to set this format for 8 characters?

Comment: this approach adds only spaces, but not shorten the string. please add some strings for testing to the question along with the wanted result.

Comment: 116-117 (Market Cap)

https://codepen.io/damiansonek/pen/oNgPKKM

Comment: i am using `replace`, your code has `match` and works different. by matching, the last portion goes. by using match, you need another quantifier for having an empty part, like `/.{1,3}(?=(...)*$)/g`

Comment: You helped me a lot. Thank you very much.
Replacing `+$` to `*$` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Number.toLocaleString` and then replace the `,` with spaces.

```js
let num = '123 123 12';
let out = Number(num.replace(/\s/g, '')).toLocaleString('us-US', {maximumFractionDigits: 5}).replace(/,/g, ' ');
console.log(out)
```

Comment: i guess you should specify locale string to toLocaleString, the above code, for instance, is not working for me.

Comment: To use the browser's default locale, omit this argument, so in my case ("it-IT") the separator is . not ,
`var formatted = (fcqInteger * valPrice).toLocaleString('us-US').replace(/\./g," ")`

Comment: @Nico added the locale thanks for pointing out, also updated to handle decimal.